# Setup and deployment project doesnt create shorcuts after installation!

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment

I have created a project and made it to install using setup and deployment wizard. When i install it in my PC, it installs properly and creates shortcuts in desktop and startmenu. But when i install it in remote PC which is in Brazil. Shortcuts are not created and i cant see it in start menu also.

Operating system for both systems is same Win XP SP3.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit: The remote system language is Brazil

Comment: Maybe the security settings are very strict on the PC?  I would try installing as administrator and see if that works.

Comment: Are you using hard coded paths or are you using the special folder macros to install your shortcuts? You have to keep in mind that in other countries, the special folders may be in their laguage and not in english.

Comment: Are you sure that it's being installed on the remote pc. Try run as admin, to make sure the installer has the right Privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer I can think of is that the icons are installed under another profile instead of for all users.  Can you search under the "Documents and Settings" folder for your icons?  That would tell you if they were installed under someone else (maybe the account you use to install the package.

Another thing to check is to be sure your computer didn't have icons before you installed it.  If you have been using your PC to test the installation, maybe a previous one left the icons there and it is masking the fact that you aren't really installing the icons anywhere.

Finally, check your permissions for the computer in Brazil.  Maybe you don't have administrative rights to write to the "All Users" locations.  It could be you have permissions to install your application (especially if you aren't installing it in "Program Files" but it is possible even if you have those rights) but you don't have rights to those folders.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from guessing, run the installer with verbose logging:

```
msiexec /i "Setupfile.msi" /L*v "C:\InstallLog.txt"
```

Then open the log file in the Windows Installer Log Util to make it more legible:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372811(v=vs.85).aspx